# Using optional Parameter

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, wcf

I'm trying to you a web service with my MVC3 controller. This service has an optional parameter, such as

```
Service.GetObject(int id, DateTime? date)
```

But when I try to call it will a null value , like

```
Service.GetObject(id, null)
```

I get this error.

> $exception    {"Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other
>   types."}  System.Exception
>   {System.ServiceModel.FaultException}

Please help if you can.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the service is trying to cast from DBNull to some other type (DBNull != null) and since the code you show has no notion of DBNull it's hard to say what the problem is but it doesn't look like it's in the client code

Answer (score -1):

You should't have to even use null for the second parameter in your call.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2011/02/02/asp-net-mvc-3-optional-parameter-routing-issue.aspx

Comment: OP is calling a service from his controller it's not an action with an optional parameter